# For homebrew mysql installs, where's my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

For homebrew mysql installs, where's my.cnf? Does it install one?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

There is no my.cnf by default.  As such, MySQL starts with all of the default settings.  If you want to create your own my.cnf to override any defaults, place it at /etc/my.cnf.

Also, you can run `mysql --help` and look through it for the conf locations listed.

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
```

As you can see, there are also some options for bypassing the conf files, or specifying other files to read when you invoke mysql on the command line.

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case; I see a my.cnf file in /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.15/ (or whichever version you have installed)

Comment: @williamt "mysql --help" doesn't list that file as being used, I think it's just a default that comes with the installation files

Comment: @williamt I think Vinicius is right. I see /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.20_1/my.cnf but when I added the log-bin to it and restarted mysqld, it still didn't haven't binary logging enabled. It wasn't until I copied that my.cnf to /etc/my.cnf that binary logging was enabled. Perhaps that my.cnf file is used during the initial install, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm on 5.6.26 and I don't see it there.

Comment: On on 5.6.26 can be lolcated by running: 
`ls $(brew --prefix mysql)/*.cnf`

Comment: `mysql --help | grep cnf` was actually easier to find the lines.

Comment: @Mark if you take a look at the init.d script in support-files/mysql.server, you can see it checks for an /etc/my.cnf

Comment: To add to @vynyll's snippet, adding 1 before-context line to grep makes the filtered docs a bit easier to read: `mysql --help | grep -B 1 cnf`

Comment: Interesting that if you want to change the bind-address, you can't because it's overridden in the cli args. Turns out the plist actually has it: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

Comment: As of now (Feb. 2020) `my.cnf` is located under `/usr/local/etc` (`mysql@5.7` brew formula)

Comment: I use "mdfind -name my.cnf" to find my.cnf file

Answer (score 276):

The homebrew mysql contains sample configuration files in the installation's support-files folder.

```sh
ls $(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/my-*
```

If you need to change the default settings you can use one of these as a starting point.

```sh
cp $(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/my-default.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

As @rednaw points out, a homebrew install of MySQL will most likely be in `/usr/local` so the my.cnf file should not be added to the system `/etc` folder, so I’ve changed the command to copy the file into `/usr/local/etc`.

If you are using MariaDB rather than MySQL use the following:

```sh
cp $(brew --prefix mariadb)/support-files/my-small.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: `sudo cp $(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf`

Comment: If Homebrew installed MySQL in `/usr/local/` (which is the default I think), you can also place the `my.conf` in `/usr/local/etc/`, which don't require root privileges.

Comment: brew --prefix mysql doesn't give the correct path, for me, it shows '/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16', but indeed mariadb is installed in '/usr/local/opt/mariadb/'

Comment: @zhaozhi Use `brew --prefix mariadb`. In the MariaDB distribution the `my-default.cnf` does not exist - so use `my-small.cnf`. Try this `cp $(brew --prefix mariadb)/support-files/my-small.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer. The first one is incorrect. The question asked was relating to homebrew.

Comment: This solution was help me, although I installed the percona-server. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

One way to find out:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
# wait a few minutes for it to finish
locate my.cnf
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I learned about locate.updatedb. However, there is no config file by default, see the answer below

Comment: You can use `mdfind -name my.cnf` instead of `locate` command on OSX

Comment: For me `locate my.cnf` worked directly. I didn't run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/.bottle/etc/my.cnf` and
`/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

was what I got

Answer (score 26):

Add another answer cause

- The accepted anwser is right. Since we're talking about Homebrew installed `mysql`, not MySQL installed manually, there's more direct way to find the conf.
- The former answers may be a little outdated, Homebrew on M1 Mac is stored in a different location

#### Conf

The `my.cnf` is copied by Homebrew to following places during installation

- `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` for x86 Mac
- `/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf` for M1 Mac

Homebrew chooses `/usr/local`, or `/opt/homebrew` to store packages, so the default conf files are not stored in `/etc/` but `/usr/local/etc` or `/opt/homebrew/etc`.

In fact, homebrew changed the `-DSYSCONFDIR=` (default conf location) flag during compiling `mysql` from source.

#### Start the Service

A short answer: run `brew info mysql` and check the tips.

The recommended way is `brew services start mysql`, which uses the `launchd` to manage services. (`launchd` is deemed a `systemd` alternative on macOS)

For anyone wanna start it manually, `mysql.start` without any option is enough to start the service. (`mysql.start` is a script provided by `mysql` to help start the service)

Comment: You can also use `brew services run mysql` which runs the server without setting it up for auto-start.

Comment: thanks ! for pointing out this one. /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf for M1 Mac

Answer (score 25):

in my system it was

```
nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.default
```

as template and

```
nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

as working.

Answer (score 20):

Nothing really helped me - I could not overwrite settings in a /etc/my.cnf file.
So I searched like John suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/7974114/717251

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
# wait a few minutes for it to finish
locate my.cnf
```

It found another my.cnf in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/my.cnf
```

changing this file worked for me! Don't forget to restart the launch Agent:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

---

Update:

If you have a fairly recent installation of homebrew you should use the brew services commands to restart mysql (use your installed homebrew mysql version, i.e. mysql or mysql@5.7):

```
brew services stop mysql
brew services start mysql
```

Comment: I think you can also run `brew services stop mysql` and `brew services start mysql` in place of the `launchctl unload ...` lines.

Comment: That ist true - but at the time of writing this answer these homebrew commands were not yet available. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 19):

Since `mysql --help` shows a list of files, I find it useful to pipe the result to `ls` to see which of them exist:

```
$ mysql --help | grep /my.cnf | xargs ls
ls: /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory
ls: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: No such file or directory
ls: ~/.my.cnf: No such file or directory
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

For my (Homebrew installed) MySQL 5.7, it seems the files is on `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: /usr/local is correct for home-brew on an intel Mac. with Apple Silicon home-brew is now at /opt/homebrew and the paths are changing

Answer (score 13):

On your shell type `my_print_defaults --help`

At the bottom of the result, you should be able to see the file from which the server reads the configurations. It prints something like this:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: this is it! thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Server version: 8.0.19 Homebrew. macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and installed MySQL via Homebrew. Found this file here:

```
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180898/2031033) helped :)

Answer (score 6):

You can find where the `my.cnf` file has been provided by the specific package, e.g.

```
brew list mysql # or: mariadb
```

In addition to verify if that file is read, you can run:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep my.cnf
```

which will show you filesystem activity in real-time related to that file.

Comment: Brilliant! With grep, amazing!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer is no. Installing one in ~/.my.cnf or /usr/local/etc seems to be the preferred solution.

Comment: On my MBP only /etc/my.cnf allows me affect the Homebrew installation of mysql.

Answer (score 2):

run

`sudo find / -name my.cnf`

Usually the first result is the correct one.
Should be in

`/usr/local/etc/`

Answer (score 1):

In case of Homebrew, mysql would also look for my.cnf in it's Cellar directory, for example:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/my.cnf
```

For the case one prefers to keep the config close to the binaries - create `my.cnf` here if it's missing.

Restart mysql after change:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac m1 (Apple silicon), the my.cnf is located at

```
/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

and can also be found by `mysql --help`

Answer (score 0):

I have installed MySQL 5.7 using Homebrew

my.cnf file is located in "/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf"

Answer (score -1):

For MacOS (High Sierra), MySQL that has been installed with home brew.

Increasing the global variables from mysql environment was not successful. So in that case creating of ~/.my.cnf is the safest option. Adding variables with [mysqld] will include the changes (Note: if you change with [mysql] , the change might not work).

> <~/.my.cnf>  [mysqld]   connect_timeout = 43200   max_allowed_packet =
>   2048M   net_buffer_length = 512M

Restart the mysql server. and check the variables.
y

> sql> SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;
>   +----------------------+ | @@max_allowed_packet |
>   +----------------------+ |           1073741824 |
>   +----------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score -1):

1. `$ps aux | grep mysqld
   /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/plugin`
2. Drop your my.cf file to `/usr/local/opt/mysql`
3. `brew services restart mysql`