# ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1: MySQL server has gone away

I am facing the same problem.  I am trying to restore mysqldump file to my machine. The file have size of 2.7 MB. I am getting  "ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1: MySQL server has gone away" error. I increased size of max_allowed_packet and wait_timeout. But nothing worked.

Following are the content of my file (my-medium.ini), please suggest 
me where I am wrong. My installation have various ini files, and I have 
modified, my-large, my-medium, my-small, my-huge, my-innodb-heavy-4G. Thanks in advance!!

---

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
wait_timeout = 6000

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: Any reply!! Does no one knows solution of this :(

Comment: I dont think there is any such issue, If I ma restoring dump from my local machine then it is working fine. It is giving error only when I am importing dump from mysql table created on server.

Comment: try mysqldump with --max_allowed_packet=<value> option.

Comment: I'm using xampp to run MySQL locally and it comes with the same set of ini file (small, medium, large, huge, heavy 4G). When importing a csv file I've either a _#2006 - MySQL server has gone away_ or _1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes_ message. @Sangeeta did you find a solution? 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that this error was happening because I was using "windows power-shell" instead of command prompt :)) Solved!!!

Answer (score 47):

Change 3 settings in my.cnf file

Under [mysqld]

```
max_allowed_packet = 64M
wait_timeout = 6000
```

Under [mysqldump]

```
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

That should fix it

Answer (score 3):

This usually means that you have "incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server", see [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html).  I ran into this same issue and simply had to run:

```
mysql_upgrade --password
```

The documentation states that, "mysql_upgrade should be executed each time you upgrade MySQL".

Answer (score 0):

Answers above can help, just adding my suggestion in addition as you can just bypass restrictions by directing using source command to import.
As an alternative to mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql, you can first login to mysql, select database and then import by source as below.

```
mysql -u username -p    
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source path-to/file.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while restoring a bigger table:
"SQL Fehler (2006): MySQL server has gone away".

Solution:
Used smaller queries. Do not export big queries with comma separated rows. Changed it to single "INSERT" or "REPLACE" per row.

Answer (score -1):

Under `[mysqld]` I have tried the following:

```
max_allowed_packet = 2096M
```

restarted mysqld and it did not work, however what worked for me is to set `max_allowed_packet` globally from command line and then run the export from dump, it went through without any issues.

You can start from smaller packet size depending on database, I also did reimport my database with same size.

**For Export:-**

```
mysqldump --opt --user=confluenceUser --password='<passwd>' --max_allowed_packet=2147483648 confluencedb | gzip > confluencedb.sql.gz
```

**For Import:-**

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=2147483648;

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

zcat confluence.sql.gz | mysql -uconfluence -p<passwd> confluencedb
```