# Can't import on command line

Tags: mysql

I've tried to import a sql file (340Mb) with this statement:

```
mysql -u <user> -p --max_allowed_packet=1024M <database> < <file>.sql
```

And I get the error message after a while:

"ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line : MySQL server has gone away"

However if I use a MySQL manager like in this case Sequel Pro it works fine.

Can't understand why it doesn't work on the command line.

Comment: see this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/18417847/2286537

Comment: Thank you, that worked @krishn-patel