# Importing larger SQL files into MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a 400 MB large SQL backup file. I'm trying to import that file into MySQL database using *WAMP* → *import*, but the import was unsuccessful due to many reasons such as upload file size is too large and so on. So, I've gone ahead and made a few changes to the configuration of PHP and MySQL settings under WAMP. Changes made are

```
Under WAMP->MySQL->my.ini

    max_allowed_packet = 800M
    read_buffer_size = 2014K

 Under WAMP->PHP->PHP.ini

    max_input_time = 20000
    memory_limit = 128M
```

Is this the right way to import such a large SQL file using *WAMP* → *import*?

If so, did I make the right changes to the configuration files? What are the maximum values allowed for the above variable?

Comment: You will have to import it in the command line

Comment: For big files always try with terminal/cmd .. Never go with UI.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can import large files this command line way:

```
mysql -h yourhostname -u username -p databasename < yoursqlfile.sql
```

Comment: @lbu Thanks. But i've never used mysql command line in my laptop. I always use MySQL workbench. Is there a way to launch mysql command line from workbench?

Comment: Looks like a good excuse to start learning it, you don't need to be an expert to use it, all the stuff you can do on workbench work just fine on the command line

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And i knew that i don't need to be an expert to use it. Earlier i've used putty to connect to the server and connected to mysql shell using the command `mysql -h hostname -u username -D databasename -p`. And now, i'm trying to connect to my own laptop but couldn't. Otherwise i am good.  Thanks again.

Comment: for large database more than 4 GB its taking much time.

Comment: This way may cause errors. The best way is to use `mysql> source` (see other answers)

Answer (score 47):

Use this from mysql command window:

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql;
```

Comment: I like this solution better because it shows the output of running the script.

Comment: You can execute an SQL script file using the source command or \. command:

`mysql> source file_name`
`mysql> \. file_name`

  [Referrence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Comment: Will  ```source``` perform well for 50GB file?

Comment: @wwwwan yes, I have just now successfully sourced a 2.6 Gb .sql file. It just takes a little while. You might need to increase the allowed packet size, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12792977/1685346).

Comment: One caveat is that this method makes it harder to see any errors that might have occurred during the import.

Answer (score 44):

Since you state (in a clarification comment to another person's answer) that you are using MySQL Workbench, you could try using the "sql script" option there. This will avoid the need to use the commandline (although I agree with the other answer that it's good to climb up on that horse and learn to ride).

1. In MySQL Workbench, go to File menu, then select "open script". This is probably going to take a long time and might even crash the app since it's not made to open things that are as big as what you describe.
2. The better way is to use the commandline. Make sure you have MySQL client installed on your machine. This means the actual MySQL (not Workbench GUI or PhpMyAdmin or anything like that). Here is [a link describing the command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html). Once you have that downloaded and installed, open a terminal window on your machine, and you have two choices for slurping data from your file system (such as in a backup file) up into your target database. One is to use 'source' command and the other is to use the < redirection operator.

Option 1:
from the directory where your backup file is:

```
$mysql -u username -p -h hostname databasename < backupfile.sql
```

Option 2:
from the directory where your backup file is:

```
$mysql -u username -p -h hostname
[enter your password]
> use databasename;
> source backupfile.sql
```

Obviously, both of these options require that you have a backup file that is SQL.

Comment: The "source" method worked for me when the "regular" command line method didn't. It also has the benefit of showing the execution activity in real time.

Comment: ya source method is work for me to at least its showing the progress of query. but taking much time . Is any method to reduce upload time.

Answer (score 7):

You can make the import command from any SQL query browser using the following command:

```
source C:\path\to\file\dump.sql
```

Run the above code in the query window ... and wait a while :)

This is more or less equal to the previously stated command line version. The main difference is that it is executed from within MySQL instead. For those using non-standard encodings, this is also safer than using the command line version because of less risk of encoding failures.

Comment: Reference, for anyone who was curious: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem, but in Windows. I was trying to figure out how to open a large MySQL SQL file in Windows, and these are the steps I had to take:

- Go to the download website (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).
- Download the MySQL Community Server and install it (select the developer or full install, so it will install client and server tools).
- Open the MySQL command-line client from the Start menu.
- Enter your password used in install.
- In the prompt, *mysql>*, enter:

  ```
    CREATE DATABASE database_name;

    USE database_name;

    SOURCE myfile.sql
  ```

That should import your large file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest way is to upload the file using MYSQL command line.

using the command from the terminal to access MySQL command line and run *source*

```
    mysql --host=hostname -uuser -ppassword
    source filename.sql
```

or directly from the terminal

```
   mysql --host=hostname -uuser -ppassword < filename.sql
```

at the prompt.

Comment: URL is bad, and the Internet Archive doesn't seem to have a viable cached copy

Comment: This is already covered in previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

We have experienced the same issue when moving the sql server in-house.

A good solution that we ended up using is splitting the sql file into chunks. There are several ways to do that. Use

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/ seems good (but never used it)

http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/ used it and it was very useful to get structure out of the mess and you can take it from there.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Three things you have to do, if you are doing it locally:

In `php.ini` or `php.cfg` of your PHP installation

```
post_max_size=500M

upload_max_filesize=500M

memory_limit=900M
```

Or set other values. **Restart Apache**.

*Or*

Use the PHP [big dump tool](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/). It’s best ever I have seen. It’s free and open source.

Comment: What if the database is 10G? Should you change upload_max_filesize to 10G? This is not good approach

Comment: @bksi if you have 10 GB file then use bigdump i have tested by 17 GB database file

Comment: There is much easy way to import without using additional programs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the source command on Windows remember to use `f:/myfolder/mysubfolder/file.sql` and not `f:\myfolder\mysubfolder\file.sql`

Comment: The normal windows back slashes are no problem on Windows XAMPP. Any evidence for your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a few months old but for other people looking --

A simpler way to import a large file is to make a sub directory 'upload' in your folder c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.2
and edit this line in the config.inc.php file in the same directory to include the folder name
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';

Then place the incoming .sql file in the folder /upload.

Working from inside the phpmyadmin console, go to the new database and import.  You will now see an additional option to upload files from that folder.  Chose the correct file and be a little patient.  It works.

If you still get a time out error try adding $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; to the same config.inc.php file.

I have had difficulty importing an .sql file where the user name was root and the password differed from my the root password on my new server.  I simply took off the password before I exported the .sql file and the import worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

On item 1.16 of phpMyAdmin they say:

**1.16 I cannot upload big dump files (memory, HTTP or timeout problems).**

---

Starting with version 2.7.0, the import engine has been re–written and these problems should not occur. If possible, upgrade your phpMyAdmin to the latest version to take advantage of the new import features.

The first things to check (or ask your host provider to check) are the values of `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max`_size in the `php.ini` configuration file. All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP. One user also said that `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` need to be larger than upload_max_filesize. There exist several workarounds if your upload is too big or your hosting provider is unwilling to change the settings:

Look at the `$cfg['UploadDir']` feature. This allows one to upload a file to the server via scp, ftp, or your favorite file transfer method. PhpMyAdmin is then able to import the files from the temporary directory. More information is available in the Configuration of this document.

Using a utility (such as [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)) to split the files before uploading. We cannot support this or any third party applications, but are aware of users having success with it.

If you have shell (command line) access, use MySQL to import the files directly. You can do this by issuing the “source” command from within MySQL:

```
source filename.sql;
```

Comment: Hmmm... although this is technically possible, it's far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench). Just copy the .sql file text to the query window of MySQL Workbench and just execute it. All renaming things will done by it.

Comment: The problem here is that, for large files, Workbench errors out while importing them. That's why you basically need to use the command line.

Comment: Thanks @SeanDuggan will try this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the import progress. Install pv with brew and run this:

```
brew install pv
pv -p dump.sql | mysql -h localhost -u root -p db_name
```

Answer (score -3):

**my.ini**

```
max_allowed_packet = 800M
read_buffer_size = 2014K
```

**PHP.ini**

```
max_input_time = 20000
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size=128M
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain why this solves the problem?

Comment: Increasing the limits is no solution. Use mysql command for large sql imports.