# How to import a 600mb .sql file in phpMyAdmin by typing command?

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

I want to import a 600mb .sql file into phpMyAdmin. As I have memory limitation in server, I can't use import option given in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: you cant do that in phpmyadmin however in mysql cli you can do so.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278375/importing-larger-sql-files-into-mysql

Comment: I'm getting this error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u <uid> –-password=<pwd> <database> < newmagdb.sql' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql
```

If it's not clear, look for how to load from a dump file.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u [username] -p [dbname] < [path for the sql file to be imported]
```

You can use this in mysql command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin Can only do this if the server settings are sufficiently generous to allow you to upload such a large file.

If you have command line client then you should use the mysql client. If you don't have command line access then [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) is a very good tool for importing large SQL files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have memory limitations in the server and you are using phpmyadmin, you have to manually split the sql file or use a tool to split the file based on your memory restrictions and import file by file.