# How to Import 800MB .sql file to XAMPP for windows /phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to import over 800MB size sql file to `MySQL` database in localhost `XAMPP/phpmyadmin`. But phpmyadmin UI doesn't allow to import more than 2MB.

What are the possible ways to do that such as any `SQL` query to import `.sql` file ?

Thank you in advance

I found that I can change the following values to php.ini file in xampp

```
post_max_size = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

What is the bect time for execution and input in order to not have exceptions and upload my file successfully?

Because it gives me something like this (this happens when I try to upload the zip file from sql file):

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 728760320) (tried to allocate 723280395 bytes) in C:\xampp2\phpMyAdmin\libraries\zip_extension.lib.php on line 55
```

When I try to upload the pure sql file it gives me this:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp2\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 290
```

I have set in php.ini file the following:

```
post_max_size=1800M
max_execution_time=10000000
max_input_time=10000000
upload_max_filesize=900M
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing larger sql files into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278375/importing-larger-sql-files-into-mysql)

Comment: @RahilWazir Thank you for your comment. I am using xampp and not wamp. Possible it is the same process but I don't know to use the MySQL command line like the accepted answer mentions. Any help could be more than helpful and welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can run that command from windows command prompt (cmd) by navigating to your `\xampp\mysql\bin` folder. Make sure you change the parameters and specify correct path to your `database.sql` file

Answer (score 0):

You can try using command prompt by using the below command

`mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`
Enter then enter the password

It must work for large sql file.

Comment: Hi, i know this question is old enough. But what should i see after issuing the command? only a cursor and cannot type anything? is that it? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to enter your mysql password