# Mysql has gone away .. but really did not

Tags: mysql

Hi have this really strange problem. Every query executed in mysql returns: "mysql has gone away" followed by a normal result.

Looks like this:

```
mysql> select 1 ;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    833332004
Current database: *** NONE ***

+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It happens regardless of which query is executed from any connections. Is there any way of recovering from this without restarting the process ?

This happened after an issue with code that occurred that caused legitimate "mysql has gone away" state. The root cause has been fixed, the db load and conn count dropped, yet, the message remains stuck. Looks like a bug to me, but I want to avoid restart if possible.

Comment: There are a number of things that might interrupt your MySQL connection. "Gone away" is the message displayed when the client has to reconnect.

Comment: what is `wait_timeout` value  in your `my.cnf` file?

Comment: The message appears every time any query is executed. Each time the message appears followed by the correct result of the query. It looks like the error message is somehow "stuck" and is returned to everybody all the time...

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a command to reset something in mysql to clear this or a restart of the process is required.

Comment: @prashantthakre The wait_timeout is 8h

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: `set global max_allowed_packet=64*1024*1024;` add this line or execute by using root user and check whether problem exists.