# Mysql restoring 1GB db error 2006 BLOB Files

Tags: ssh, phpmyadmin, mysql

I am trying to backup my vbulletin db (with 1GB) using:

```
mysql -u dbusername -p databasename < backupname.sql
```

https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/maintenance_ssh_backup

and restoring with:

```
mysql -u db_user -p db_name < dumped.sql
```

ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1854: MySQL server has gone away

I can't open sql file with a text editor (big file)

I get the same error from phpmyadmin

Error

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `filedata` (`filedataid`, `userid`, `dateline`, `thumbnail_dateline`, `filedata`, `filesize`, `filehash`, `thumbnail`, `thumbnail_filesize`, `extension`, `refcount`, `width`, `height`, `thumbnail_width`, `thumbnail_height`) VALUES (40,3140,1341362558,1341362558,'�����Exif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\Z\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�(\0\0\0\0\0\0\01\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�i\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0HApple\0iPhone 3GS\0\0\0\0\0H\0\0\0\0\0\0H\0\0\05.1.1\02012:07:03 21:36:56\0\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0肝\0\0\0\0\0\0��\"\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\'\0\0\0\0�\0\0�\0\0\0\0\00221�\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0�\0\n\0\0\0\0\0 �\0\0\0\0\0\0(�\0\n\0\0\0\0\00�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0� \0\0\0\0\0 \0\0�\n\0\0\0\0\0\08�\0\0\0\0\0\0@�\0\0\0\0\00100�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�\n\[...]
```

MySQL said:

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

EDIT:
Looking into filedata I have a lot files: [BLOB - 76.4 KB]

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Hi @Mihai , thank you! I've read but couldn't find anything that can help me to solve my problem. Looking into table filedata I have a lot files [BLOB - 76.4 KB]. What you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away). Additional information/troubleshooting suggestions [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysql parameter Max_allowed_packet, it might be smaller to handle & restore the blob data.
Try increasing max_allowed_packet to 512M and restart MySQL service where dump is to be restored.
And then try again the MySQL restoration.
Best luck!!