# yii mysql server has gone away on insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I am trying one cron job after running of 5 minutes it is giving me below error.

Here by i am attaching screen shot for that.I am using yii framework.

[image: I am trying one cron job after running of 5 minutes it is giving me below error.]

```
  CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
  General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away. 
  The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `phpcrawler_links` 
  (`site_id`, `depth`, `crawl_now`, `url`, `last_crawled`, 
  `http_status_code`, `content_type`, `page_size`, `parent_url_id`) 
  VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7, :yp8)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: @iroegbu Its error is duplicate but sitation is different and same solution is not working here

Answer (score 2):

It often happens due to several inserts in a big loop, and one of the INSERT fails. Normally, the MySQL server resumes after a while without having to do anything.

But be sure to tweak your max_packet_size to some large amount in my.ini and restart your server:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

Verify by:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%packet%';
```

Comment: How can I make changes in hosting site ?using php.ini or some thing else

Comment: First, confirm that your loop isn't that big enough to affect the performance. If you really need it, you can request them to increase it.

Comment: i marked that problem not is coming with but some insert query.which is giving this error

Comment: i fired above query and it has given me below details 

max_allowed_packet  67108864
slave_max_allowed_packet  1073741824

Answer (score 2):

If you use columns text that maybe take serialized data and many rows you must consider to increase these parameters:

```
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

If you have a lot of request set this and don't set it to bigger because its related with your environment

```
max_connections=1000
```

**Note** If you are in last case and if you are using persistent connection take a look to disable it, in many application that have close interaction with database if you create many connections persistent you consume that number so fast.