# How do I correct a ERROR 2006 (HY000) on windows server 2012 r2 on godaddy VPS?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I recently reprovisioned my server from MS 2008 r2 to MS 2012 r2 and tried to restore the database but I the following error:

```
Unable to restore database 'mediawiki_1'
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 848: MySQL server has gone away
(Error code 22)
---------------------- Debug Info -------------------------------
```

In reference to the best answer found at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away?s=2|3.6649](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away?s=2%7C3.6649) I need to edit the my.cnf file to

```
 max_allowed_packet=64M
```

Can someone point me to where I can find this file/run a script in Powershell to make the necessary change?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a windows machine.  my.cnf is for linux.  On a windows machine you would have my.ini file. The default path to the my.ini file looks something like `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`.  Although, you may have an older version and/or your default path maybe different.

I would run this command `dir *my.ini* /s` in ms-dos(command prompt) from the root directory (C:) and you should be able to find the file that way.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2. When i put that command in PowerShell it is not valid.  Is my.ini different from the .user.ini file?

Comment: If you need to run it in PowerShell, `cd c: ; dir *my.ini* -recurse`

Comment: i also get no results. I am unable to locate ms-dos on my machine, but I could very well be dumb.

Comment: @BK435 Thanks! Still ineffective.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\>dir *my.ini* /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E498-D82D
File Not Found

c:\>dir *.my.ini* /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E498-D82D
File Not Found

Comment: c:\>
c:\>dir *.ini* \s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E498-D82D

 Directory of c:\


 Directory of c:\

File Not Found

Comment: Under My PC i just see one

Comment: I agree and same thing. Could it be a hidden drive/how would i see if there is hidden drive?

Comment: It has been resolved. I went into services, located mysql, clicked properties, and was given the path.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL\Data\my.ini

added line to file:

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
```