# MySQL Replication Stopped Syncing

Tags: mysql, replication

So my MySQL server stopped syncing about 3 weeks ago. I am having issues resyncing. It is important that I don't lock the tables to resync and creating a dump would take many hours.

Heres what I have for my Master database for SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G on my SLAVE server.

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    144527
Current database: *** NONE ***

*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3337
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000244
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 618839200
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000692
                Relay_Log_Pos: 210
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000244
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: hbjdb
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 1
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 618839200
              Relay_Log_Space: 367
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:3337' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is what I have for SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G on my MASTER server:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1478698
Current database: *** NONE ***

*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3337
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000171
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1012219985
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000031
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000171
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 1
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1012219985
              Relay_Log_Space: 106
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2013
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:3337' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
```

My slave mysql database is hosted locally while the master database is hosted by a server company.

Here are my outputs for

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE Repl_slave_priv='Y';
```

on my MASTER database

```
+------+---------------------------+
| user | host                      |
+------+---------------------------+
| root | localhost                 |
| root | c9.d.de.static.xlhost.com |
| root | 127.0.0.1                 |
| repl | 68.165.36.44              |
| repl | 127.0.0.1                 |
| root | 209.190.4.162             |
| root | 209.190.4.163             |
| root | 207.182.131.234           |
| root | %                         |
| root | 207.182.129.2             |
+------+---------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

and for my SLAVE database

```
+------------------+---------------+
| user             | host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| root             | localhost     |
| root             | %             |
| root             | 127.0.0.1     |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| repl             | 68.165.36.44  |
| repl             | 99.135.16.102 |
+------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Here is what my Master error log file looks like:

```
160608 16:40:54 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'repl@127.0.0.1:3337' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400, Error_code: 2013
160608 16:40:54 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000171' at position 1012219985, relay log './mysqld-relay-bin.000031' position: 4
```

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: See these links http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However this didn't solve my problem. This replication system was working for months and as soon as I get hired to this company and the main developer leaves it goes under. Now im stuck with the mess and I can't dump the database because the tables lock. Any help is appreciated. I just go to sleep at night pretending I have a backup database.