# 2006 Server Gone Away. (MYSQL Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to import my database to my server but the server gone away.

I already tried to change my max_allowed_packet but still not working. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: i already read it but it doesn't work.