# MYSQL server has gone away on MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb

I was using  a cron function where Server type  was MySQL and faced no issues , However I recently migrated to  a different server where : Server type: MariaDB

And I get this error :  Query error: MySQL server has gone away

The SQL query I am using is not that big .

Please assist .

Comment: PS :  If I run the cron manually there is no error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: max_allowed_packet is set to: 1073741824
 wait_timeout it set to 28800

Comment: trigger the error then check the logs using  `$ tail /var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: Is that the batch or the interactive, session or global, `wait_timeout`?

Answer (score -2):

Hi Thanks for the comments , 
The Issue was from server side, The server was restarting itself and database connectivity was getting lost for that short period of time.

Thank You