# Laravel : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I use Laravel and XAMPP on Mac OS. here my `.env` file 
when I request the data from database I get this error 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

[here the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V55Ha.png)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8443
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=rdxcft
DB_PASSWORD=rdxcft
```

and my `database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

thank for your attention

Comment: Why setting `DB_PORT` to 8443 instead of 3306?

Comment: What happens if you ping 127.0.0.1:3306 & 127.0.0.1:8443?

Comment: @KoalaYeung 8443 and 8080 is default port of my Xampp. and I have tried to use 3306 and I get error `no such file or directory`

Comment: @Patrick I get this error `ping: cannot resolve 127.0.0.1:8080: Unknown host`

Comment: 8443 and 8080 should be the default port of your Apache web server as installed by XAMPP. Not your MySQL server. Do you know the correct port to your MySQL server, if not je default 3306 port?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I don't know. how to check it ??

Comment: Please run ***** php artisan config:clear ***** command and  also run this  ****php artisan key:generate *****.

Comment: I think unless you set it otherwise, it should be 3306. Did you try setting your `DB_PORT` in your .env to 3306?

Comment: @mukeshkumar I still get the same error

Comment: @KoalaYeung I have tried and I get this error PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")

Comment: If you encounter error with the 3306 port setting, please show us the full error message. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: @KoalaYeung here the screenshot https://ibb.co/cY4c7LH

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL has started correctly? Also is there any firewall setting that may block the connection?

Comment: @Patrick I have tried that solution but still error

Comment: @KoalaYeung it runs fine on native and codeigniter php

Comment: Please check your password and username is correct or not.

Comment: @mukeshkumar my password and username is set correctly

Comment: Can you show us the codeigniter config and code that works?

Comment: @KoalaYeung If I use Xampp link http://localhost:8080/pengajian/public/about it run correctly. but when I use 127.0.0.1:8000 (the default url of Laravel) I this error
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `info`)` here the screenshot :https://ibb.co/wzyCCQr

Comment: Do you mean your Laravel setup works on your XAMPP environment, but not in the test server started by the command `artisan serve`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung yes. not in the test server started by the command `artisan serve` when retrieving data from database.