# PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel so started creating api. I already have MySQL database at local and I am trying to connect with local database but getting following logtrace.

```
php artisan migrate



PDOException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

  at /Users/sandeeparmal/...../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
    66|         if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
    67|             return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    68|         }
    69| 
  > 70|         return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    71|     }
    72| 
    73|     /**
    74|      * Determine if the connection is persistent.

  Exception trace:

  1   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8080;dbname=sample_server", "root", "", [])
      /Users/sandeeparmal/...../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8080;dbname=sample_server", "root", "", [])
      /Users/sandeeparmal/...../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:100
```

Here is my .env file  :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8080
DB_DATABASE=sample_server
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Here is my database.php  :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8080'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forcity_server'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ]
```

I tried to find solution and got solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979736/1139398) but still it's not working. I applied same on local database.

Comment: Are you sure your Mysql runs on port 8080 thats usually an alternative port to run Nginx

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying to figure these kind of errors out, try checking your SSL certificate and connecting without it.

So for this example it would be this line:
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),

Answer (score -2):

I updated to laravel 6, so I updated PHP because laravel 6 uses 7.2+
by default there wasn't php.ini and when generated, extension was off so I tried migration too and found out this

Check php.ini, there is one row

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

make it

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

save and restart apache