# how to solve MySQL server has gone with query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

I am getting below error

> "Failed inserting BLOB data into MySQL table 2006 (HY000): MySQL
>   server has gone away"

```
def insertBLOB(request):
    id =(1)
    name=("Eric")
    photo = ("/home/gauri/Pictures/w3schools.jpg")
    biodata =  ("/home/gauri/Downloads/mnum.npy")
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="", 
                    port=3307, db="data2")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_insert_blob_query = "INSERT INTO python_employee(id, name, photo, biodata) 
                                     VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        with open(photo, 'rb') as file:
            binaryData = file.read()
        with open(biodata, 'rb') as file:
            binaryData1 = file.read()

        insert_blob_tuple = (id, name, binaryData, binaryData1,)
        result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_blob_query,insert_blob_tuple)


        connection.commit()
        print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into python_employee 
              table",result)

        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed inserting BLOB data into MySQL table {}".format(error))

        return HttpResponse("data")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: May I ask why your are directly connecting to your database instead of using `django.db.connections` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into `my.cnf` file should solve your problem.

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

Here is the [explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-features-max-allowed-packet.html).

Comment: I have changed in my.cnf file but still it giving same error

Comment: did you restart it?

Comment: @gauriindani try this `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`

Comment: should i write"SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;" in my.cnf file

Comment: @gauriindani yes

Comment: still same error is there can u please elaborate for restart i have started apache server again should i have to do something else

Comment: @gauriindani `$> mysqladmin variables -u user -p` to get your max_allowed_packet variable and then do this to set it temporarily with
`mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824`

Comment: @gauriindani Also you need to reload the config files or restart the server after changing these settings

Comment: "mysqladmin variables -u user -p" for this thing i need password i forgot the password is there any other option

Comment: @gauriindani I think you need password, but look at here you may find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away