# Getting error in DBeaver mysql when try to import large sql database file

Tags: mysql, database, dbeaver

```
    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe --host=localhost --port=3306 -u root nd7b265_rahetbally
Task 'MySQL script' started at Sun May 31 09:53:09 MST 2020
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 118827: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Task 'MySQL script' finished at Sun May 31 09:53:13 MST 2020
2020-05-31 09:53:13.363 - IO error: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
2020-05-31 09:53:13.363 - java.io.IOException: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.executeProcess(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:182)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.doExecute(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:237)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.lambda$0(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:52)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.RunnableContextDelegate.lambda$0(RunnableContextDelegate.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Comment: What does the MySQL error log show (if anything)?

Answer (score 10):

Just change connection setting from `--host=localhost` to `--host=127.0.0.1`.

It works for me.

Comment: You helped me. But similar bug. In case exit code=2. I had. Thanks.

Comment: Can not believe that worked on macOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Via right click DB > SQL editor > New SQL script

Execute following queries:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979736

Answer (score 0):

At mysql client program, you can config the maxallowedpacket as below.
[image]

At the mysql server, max_allowed_package is in mysqld.conf (mysql 5.7 version)

[image]

If database size is bigger 7GB, you have to make a trick with 256MB as the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599592

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryError usually occurs when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has run out of memory to allocate. To fix this issue in DBeaver, you can try increasing the memory allocated to the JVM.

Locate the dbeaver.ini file:

On Windows, it's in the DBeaver installation directory (e.g., C:\Program Files\DBeaver).
On macOS, right-click the DBeaver application, click "Show Package Contents," and navigate to Contents/Eclipse.
On Linux, it's in the /usr/share/dbeaver directory or in the directory where you have installed DBeaver.
Open the dbeaver.ini file in a text editor.

Look for the following lines in the file:

```
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
```

These values specify the initial and maximum memory allocation for the JVM. The -Xms option sets the initial heap size, and the -Xmx option sets the maximum heap size.

Increase the memory allocation by modifying these values. For example, you could change them to:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
```

This change will set the initial heap size to 128 MB and the maximum heap size to 2048 MB (2 GB).

Save the changes to the dbeaver.ini file and close it.

Restart DBeaver for the changes to take effect.

If you still encounter OutOfMemoryError, try increasing the -Xmx value further. However, keep in mind that allocating too much memory to DBeaver may cause other applications on your system to run out of memory. Make sure to allocate a reasonable amount based on your system's available memory.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by adding these lines

wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet=100M

under [mysql] section

Comment: where is the `[mysql]` section? thanks in advance :)

Comment: where is this section?