# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away laravel mysql and xampp

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, laravel-7

i am using laravel 7 with a xampp installation. `php artisan migrate` fails and gives the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`

my .env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=****_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*******
```

i have tried `localhost` in the env file isntead of `127.0.0.1`. Worth mentioning that my xampp application launches at this address: `http://192.168.64.2/`

i have started and restated the xampp server and i have been `php artisan cache:clear` each time i make changes to the `.env` file

Comment: are there some migration of data in your migrations, this could be mysql doing a timeout

Comment: not sure what you mean but i only have migration in migrations/****_create_users_table.php and that is what im running

Comment: i used php artisan config:clear and now the error became SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: i dont know how i resolved this but its resolved. im just experiencing another error when running php artisan migrate: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching connecting to my local xampp installation and connected to an AWS RDS instance and it worked.