# Where does MySQL get its variables from if my.cnf is not present (on OS X Mountain Lion)?

Tags: mysql, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For homebrew mysql installs, where's my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973927/for-homebrew-mysql-installs-wheres-my-cnf)

I've installed MySQL on OSX Mountain Lion via Homebrew, and am having a few problems configuring the installation via a my.conf file.

Running `mysqld --help --verbose` returns the following:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-5.5
The following options may be given as the first argument:
```

followed by a bunch of different configuration options.

I'd like to set a variable by creating a my.cnf file, but whenever I try to do this (in /etc/) I get an error message about .pid files when I try to start or stop the MySQL server. I've tried to get around this by setting a value for pid-file in my.cnf, but this doesn't seem to work.

What I'd expected to see was a preexisting my.cnf file from which MySQL took the values for all the variables it lists. I'd then be able to edit that file and set the variables that I want to set. However, that file doesn't seem to exist. So where is MySQL getting its variable values from? And what's the best way to write a my.cnf file?

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973927/for-homebrew-mysql-installs-wheres-my-cnf

Answer (score 0):

As per Stephen's comment and link above, Homebrew doesn't provide a my.cnf file by default: at least not in a location where MySQL will read it. The link above provides instructions on how to use one of the boilerplate my.cnf that homebrew *does* provide to start building a my.cnf file of your own.