# Where does homebrew install PHP on Mac High Sierra?

Tags: php, path, homebrew, macos-high-sierra, php-7.2

I'm using Mac High Sierra.  I installed PHP (with GMP) using

```
brew install php72-gmp
```

Everything installed successfully, per the messages given, but it would seem I still have an old version of PHP 7.1 somewhere on my machine because when I run

```
localhost:php-7.2.1 davea$ which php
/usr/bin/php
localhost:php-7.2.1 davea$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

So I'd like to figure out where to put the homebrew version of PHP ahead in my PATH so that that version gets picked up first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT:

As of 2018 and the latest updates to Brew your php formula names have the following format `php@7.2`.

When you run `brew info php@7.2` your path should be `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/`

And there will be a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin/opt/php@7.2/`

So in order to change your php installation you just need to run this in terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or put it manually in your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"
```

===========================================================================

The location of your Homebrew installed php should be `/usr/local/Cellar/php72`

These are the steps you need to do to setup your PHP on macOS:

After you install php with brew run this in terminal:

`export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php72)/bin:$PATH"`

Then run:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

To check your current active version of php run this in terminal:

`which php`

EDIT:

run `brew info php72` in console to get all info, hints and caveats for php, it is really useful, for example this comes from brew info:

```
✩✩✩✩ PHP CLI ✩✩✩✩

If you wish to swap the PHP you use on the command line, you should add the 
following to ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile or your shell's equivalent 
configuration file:
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are familiar with linux, homebrew has its own `/opt` and `/etc` path

```
# > echo $(brew --prefix)
# /opt/homebrew
```

so the paths are (for Apple Silicon):

```
/opt/homebrew/opt
/opt/homebrew/etc
```

in linux, php is installed in `/etc/php/7.4`

in mac homebrew, php is installed in `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4`.

Please find the homebrew document on the default installation path for Apple Silicon [1](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)

ref [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973927/for-homebrew-mysql-installs-wheres-my-cnf)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have two php directories in '/usr/bin/' or '/usr/local/bin/'. If yes do a link to the good directory. See this [link](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions), may be it helps you.

Comment: I have a "/usr/bin/php" executable but in /usr/local/bin I only have "/usr/local/bin/php-cgi", "/usr/local/bin/php-config," "/usr/local/bin/phpdbg," and "/usr/local/bin/phpize."

Comment: I have installed brew and « homebrew/php/php72 ».
« php -v » return « 5.6 ».

You have just to open a new version of terminal.

Otherwise, check your PATH with echo « $PATH ». Have you « /usr/local/bin » ?

Check « /usr/local/Cellar ». Have you a php72 directory ?